# Git hooks prevent git push --force-with-lease. Any alternative to rebasing?

Tags: git

I am currently working with a group for a university project, and we all have our separate branches to develop on. I just merged in my teammate's branch and am looking to update my branch with his code. Okay, no problem. I'll just rebase, great, that works, now I gotta update the remote branch. Okay I run `git push --force-with-lease`. Push denied? Aw shucks now what?

So I discussed this with my TA, and it seems that any forced pushes are rejected. I don't think I can change this at all. Is there an alternative to the rebase strategy I described above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Merge instead of rebase? (Although now that you _have_ rebased, that's going to be tricky.)

Answer (score 0):

If it is your personal branch, and if the server accepts branch deletions : you can delete your remote branch and recreate it :

```
git push origin -d my/branch
git push origin my/branch
```

Comment: Unfortunately we're not allowed to delete anything. The instructors want to see every commit and branch and have them in history. I ended up just merging.